# Python: Can't install lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win32.whl

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pip, lxml

This started with an attempted install of lxml.

```
python -m pip install lxml
```

The error message:

```
********************************************************************************

Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
       ********************************************************************************
error: command '"C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C with exit status 2
```

My environment:

- Python 2.7 (r27:82525) W32
- pip 7.1.2

Pointers in StackOverflow suggest downloading and installing the lxml Windows binary from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

I've downloaded lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win32.whl

running:

```
 pip install lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win32.whl gives the following error messages:

Processing c:\users\xxxxx\downloads\lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win32.whl
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 294, in   run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 334, in   prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 491, in _prepare_file
session=self.session)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 814, in unpack_url
unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 723, in unpack_file_url
unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 645, in unpack_file
flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 531, in unzip_file
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfp, allowZip64=True)
  File "c:\python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 684, in __init__
self._GetContents()
  File "c:\python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 710, in _GetContents
self._RealGetContents()
  File "c:\python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 722, in _RealGetContents
raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

Suggestions are most appreciated